# Making full width and height of three divs horizontally in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

My question is i need to make three partitions in my web site, which stick in to the full screen as follows,
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nC7k.png)

But what happens currently is it just kept in center. I want to make it full width,
Following is my Bootstrap HTML code.

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

<body>

<div class="container">
    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.    
    </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:green;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
```

I need to make it as above, but any other alternative solutions will be accepted too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See snippet in **Full Page**

```css
.row, .col-sm-4, .container {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
width: 100%!important;  
}

body, html {
height: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

<body>

<div class="container">
    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.    
    </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:green;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Remove your container div and give this class name to your first row

```
row-fluid
```

like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:green;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.    
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,It worked. how can i make each and every column full screen size(height)?It depends on the size of text

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 3 you should use `.container-fluid`.

`.row-fluid` was a bootstrap 2 thing.